# How would you translate "Como en su día fueron..."

Tags: traducción

Hyperloop is a conceptual high-speed transportation system put forward by Elon Musk. A recent article begins with:

> **Como en su día fueron los dirigibles o incluso los aviones**, Hyperloop empieza a ser conocido como el medio de transporte del futuro.

What is a good translation for the first part of this sentence?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking. Do you want a full translation?

Comment: Hi Sam, Welcome to this site. Please, next time try to translate yourself and then we'll help you with the translation. We want to be a learning resource, not a translation service, so it is important that your questions asking for translation show at least some effort trying to translate.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking. Are you asking us to correct your Spanish translation? That's off-topic. Are you asking us to translate the Spanish phrase into English? That's also off-topic.  If, on the other hand, you simply have a question about your translation into Spanish, that will be on topic, but you need to be more specific.  What are your *specific* questions about the translation you attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Spanish, this is my suggestion:

> **Like on its day were the blimps or even the airplanes**, Hyperloop starts to be known as the future's mode of transport.

I know you asked for the translation of just the first part, but just in case I also translated the rest.

Comment: Can anybody tell me why I got a negative vote on my answer, please? Was it because the translation is wrong or because I answered to an off-topic question? If it's the second, in my defense I'd say that it wasn't marked as off-topic by the time I answered it.

Comment: It is impossible to know the reason for sure. Since the translation seems to be accurate, I would say that (sadly) is the latter case. That is unfortunate, since downvoting you should have nothing to do with the governance process of the question. There could be a third option, and maybe someone thinks that for any reason your answer is "not useful" or a "bad answer", but the truth is that I have seen plenty of sort answers like this in the site, so I don't think that there is anything specially wrong with yours. Maybe this could/should spark a discussion in the meta section.

Comment: @JoeMB Thank you very much Joe :-) Yes, I know that the second part translates to "Hyperloop begins to be known as the future's mode of transportation", and I was the first part that I was previously unsure of. I really appreciate your clarification.